# Vectorizing a short loop such that Octave matches Matlab speed

Tags: matlab, octave

My code takes ~0.003s to run in Octave and ~0.0007 in Matlab. Since Octave doesn't have JIT compiling, I imagine Matlab is doing behind-the-scenes optimization I should be doing myself.

```
numerators = zeros(1, 64);
for c = 1 : C
  numerators(c) = py(c) * prod(diag(px{c}(:, x)));
end
```

`py` is a `1xC` row vector. `px` is an array with `C` elements, each of which is a `DxV` matrix. `x` is a `Dx1` column vector whose values are discrete on `[1-V]`.

That `prod(diag(...))` oddity is a vectorized way of multiplying `px{c}(d, x(d))` for all `d`:

```
p = 1;
for d = 1 : D
  p *= px{c}(d, x(d))
endfor
```

`cellfun` might work, but am bogged down in the details of passing arguments. (If it *can* be done, just say so and I'll figure out how myself). Another option might be to use a 3-D matrix for `px`, however, I tried this and am enough of a newb that I couldn't get anything working.

Comment: can you add some information about the goals of this process, so we can better understand how it might be reformulated?

Comment: Timings that short aren't accurate.  Better to repeat code 1000 times in that case.

Comment: tmpearce -- If you know about Naive Bayes, I am trying to compute the numerator of p(y=k|x) for all classes, thus, p(y=k)*PROD_d p(x_d|y=k) for all k. Thus, py is a multinomial distribution over y (with 64 classes), and px are the class-conditional (px{c}) distributions over dimensions of x, thus, with D dimensions and V possible values for x, px{c} is a DxV matrix.

Comment: Richie -- the code above runs 100,000 times, for each data point. Octave is indeed ~2-3 times slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give this a shot based on the information you've provided.  I don't have timing information though.

1. Make `px` a 3D matrix `DxVxC` (instead of `1xC` cell array of `DxV` 2D matrices)
2. `px_new=px(:,x,:)` reorganizes the matrix, putting your values of interest into the main diagonal of the first two dimensions
3. Create a logical index with ones on the diagonal (`mask=eye(D,D);`); repmat so it is the size of C in the third dimension.
4. Index into `px_new` and `reshape`, so that there are `C` columns.
5. `prod` the columns, leaving a `1xC` vector
6. Multiply this (element-wise) with `py` to get your output

   ```
   px = nan(3,4,5);    %# create test 3D matrix  
   px(:, :, 1) = [1 2 3 4; 4 5 6 4; 7 8 9 4]; 
   px(:,:,2)=px(:,:,1)*1.5;  
   px(:,:,3)=px(:,:,2)*1.5;  
   px(:,:,4)=px(:,:,3)*1.5;      
   px(:,:,5)=px(:,:,4)*1.5;  
   x = [4 2 3];            %# 1xD vector discrete on 1-V  
   px_new=px(:,x,:);       %# reorganize into DxDxC  

   idx=logical(repmat(eye(size(pd_new,1))),[1,1,size(pd_new,3)])); %# logical index  
   P = prod(reshape(pd_new(idx),[],size(pd_new,3))); %#P is now 1xC vector
   ```

This code was tested at http://www.online-utility.org/math/math_calculator.jsp

Edit: I was taking a couple of unnecessary steps originally. I've updated it to be more concise.